# Senchatest locators, selenium can't find

Tags: python, selenium, testing, katalon

Hi I'm trying to use selenium to click on some element on my web app, which i gave senchatest locator "senchatest=mainMenu_plus" (because of random ID's)
I have script in Python

```
self.addProperty = self.browser.find_element_by_id("//*[@senchatest='senchatest=mainMenu_plus']//")
```

the output is still

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="//*[@senchatest='senchatest=mainMenu_plus']//"]
```

no matter if i use .find_element_by_id or xpath

can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `browser.find_element_by_id(expression)` on an **XPATH** `expression`. If that is a unique locator based on that attribute, you should be able to use

```
self.addProperty = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@senchatest='mainMenu_plus']")
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML shared and the locator that you have been trying looks not correct. try changing it to xpath like this :

```
//div[@senchatest='mainMenu_plus']
```

and use it like this :

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@senchatest='mainMenu_plus']
")
```